# Getting better performance out of Half-Life based games on MacBook

Tags: steam, macos, source-engine

I was disappointed to find that the Mac versions of Half-Life engine games (Portal, TF2, CS:Source) have a lot of trouble running on my aluminum MacBook: as soon as there's any sort of action, the framerate drops to 5 or 10.

When it's running Windows, [the MacBook has no problem with these games](http://techreport.com/articles.x/15844/5).

So, is there anything I can do to improve the performance of Half-Life engine games on OS X?

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently updated to OSX 10.6.4, then you should boot up your mac with your OSX DVD and reinstall.  You shouldn't lose any data or apps (though a backup would be advised).

Make sure you don't install the 10.6.4 update again (duh, but I did the first time round :-p)

You can find OSX updaters [here](http://support.apple.com/downloads/) which won't go all the way without asking you.

Comment: I'm still on 10.5.8, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Maybe that *IS* the issue then?  While the games can run on 10.5.8 it is recommended that you run 10.6.3.  I think.  I could be wrong.

Comment: ah, yes, that could be it. I've been meaning to upgrade for a while…

Answer (score 1):

I believe there were issues running the games following the latest OSX software update - Steam recommended that you not update.

I've had similar issues though generally a restart of steam is the best solution for me.

Comment: Hrm, dang. Too late for the update.

Also, I find the issues come up within ~5 minutes of getting into a game… So restarting would be painfully slow.

Comment: Oh, wait, the 10.6.4 update? I'm still running 10.5.8, so I guess that's not a problem.

Comment: @David - Correct, it was the 10.6.4 update - http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1314406

Answer (score 1):

While there are likely other issues causing the problem, have you taken a look at Tweak Guides? The [Half-Life 2 optimization](http://www.tweakguides.com/HL2_1.html) guide might serve as a stopgap until you can upgrade.